# How to write unit test for following function in unittest module in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing

**test_new.py** is my main script file.

So I am writing a python program to perform mathematical operation on Roman numbers . So I am writing test cases for that also . I have written test-cases for all other function but can't figure out how to write for this function

```
def operate(input_expression):
    tokens = re.split(r'([+*/-])', input_expression)
    expression = ''
    for roman in tokens:
        if(validate_roman(roman)==True):
            expression+=str(roman_to_dec(roman))
        else:
            expression+=str(roman)
    print (expression)
    retVal = (eval(expression))
    return (dec_to_roman(retVal))
```

Kindly help me with this .

I am providing input as:

```
print(operate("I+III+I"))
```

output will be :

```
1+3+1
V
```

So I made this unittest for this function :

```
def test_operate(self):
        result=test_new.operate("X+X/X")
        self.assertEqual(result,"XI")
```

Is it correct ? Or I need to make some changes  ?

Comment: Could you give some examples of input values and expected output values?

Comment: @quamrana . I have added the expected input and output . Kindly have a look at this.

Comment: The unit test looks fine. What happens when you run it?

Comment: Just a comment: Try to write functions that don't print anything. You'll never be able to write unit tests that show that they print correctly.

Comment: @quamrana. It passes well . I am asking because ,this is my first try on unittesting ,so i am not sure I am doing it the right way or not

Comment: Everything looks fine. You should make sure that you have more cases. One assert in each of many test functions. You need to make sure that you have covered all of the operators.

Comment: @quamrana . Okay . Thanks for the help dude  ^_^